# Finding a XT60 connector switch with indicator lights

Tags: switches, connector, light, indicator

I'm looking for an XT60 connector switch (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07K33LRW2/r](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K33LRW2)), but need one with an indicator light so I can visually verify whether a current is flowing through the circuit (reliability concerns). I see similar switches w/ indicator lights but for other types of connectors (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/Apex-RC-Products-Pack-Switch/dp/B01BQURNBQ/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BQURNBQ))

Context: connecting external battery to an OneWheel+ XR, and had reliability issues with switches in the past.

Current Requirements: ~60V, ~5A

I looked online for about two hours, and wasn't able to find either:

1. a XT60 connector switch that had a LED indicator built-in, or
2. a stand-alone XT60 connector LED indicator (except for https://www.readymaderc.com/products/details/STRIX-XT60-RGB-LED-Tap, which requires soldering tools that I lack)

Would love some pointers for either of the above, or general advice in steering me toward other investigations.

Comment: You're unlikely to find one that lights when a current is flowing. They'll almost certainly only indicate that a voltage is present.

Comment: look for an `illuminated DPST switch` ... connect it in a way that the lamp is on the switched side